# Calculate perimeter of convex hull in opencv

Tags: c++

For detection of table I need to calculate perimeter of convex hull in each connected component.  I wrote the following code, but it is giving wrong answer.

```
 findContours(rois[wp], contoursc, hierarchyh, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,     CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
double perim=0;
vector<vector<Point> > hullh(contoursc.size());
for (int i = 0; i < contoursc.size(); i++)
{
convexHull(contoursc[i], hullh[i], false);
}
for(int i=0;i<hullh.size();i++){
perim=perim + arcLength(hullh[i],true);
}
cout<<"Perimeter of convex hull = "<<peri<<"\n";
```

Can someone explain what could be the reason of wrong result.

Comment: Why are you summing up the perimeters of different convex hulls?

Comment: Its working right now.... Thanks

Comment: How is it working? Did you change the code? Could you please the answer